# How to get dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() inside the children

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to sum up total of the id inside the children with different child.
I want to get the value (getChildrenCount) from these child.

Here is the database:

[image: Database]

I have tried this one

```
//value for the jumlah pos
databaseReference.child("umumPos").child(model.getForumUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                long size = dataSnapshot1.getChildrenCount();
                holder.getTextViewPostThreadsCount().setText("Jumlah Pos: " + size);

            }

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
 });
```

Comment: Can you show the code of what you've already tried?

Comment: What is the value of size?

Comment: @PeterHaddad it will display `1`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated the question

Comment: What is the value of model.getForumUid()

Comment: @PeterHaddad It is `1`

Comment: Your code looks like it loops over all immediate children and determines the child count for each of them. Is that not what happens when you run it? If not, what happens when you run through the code in a debugger? Which lines doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it is not about the line sir, I want to know how to get the getchidlrencount.

Comment: You can get the count of child nodes with `getChildrenCount()`, just as you're doing already. Is the problem indeed that you're looping over the child nodes of the first-level snapshot, and only tracking the child count of one instead of adding them up? If so, Peter's answer is probably what you're lookking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code when you are looping, you are getting `size` equal to 1 and that's because under your second `id`, you only have one child. Try the following to add all children:

```
 long sum = 0;
 for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
 long size = dataSnapshot1.getChildrenCount();
 sum += size;
 holder.getTextViewPostThreadsCount().setText("Jumlah Pos: " + size);

        }
```

Comment: its working! but how? can you explain it more detail?

Comment: When you said that size is equal to `1` then I thought the for loop is probably iterating in the second Id which has only one child. Therefore you store the value of `1` inside `sum` then in the second iteration you probably get `4` and you add that with `sum` to get `5` in the end, which is 5 children